# Why onCompleted isn't calling in Facebook sdk 3.8 Android

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I have a question: I've copied-paste the code from Facebook sdk 
and I tried to do the conncation with Facebook. It just doesn't work...
I'm really frustrated and I don't know what else to do.
Please help... Thanks!

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
              // callback when session changes state
              @Override
              public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                if (session.isOpened()) {
                  Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    // callback after Graph API response with user object
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                      if (user != null) {
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello " + user.getName() + "!", 1).show();
                      }
                    }
                  }).executeAsync();
                }
              }
            });
    @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
      }
```

Comment: You could check out this library that makes it easier to use the facebook sdk: https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook :)

Comment: I have more one BIG problem please help me here. I tried the code it run good but than i install the app of facebook. is not conncet. you babe tell me why is it?

Answer (score 0):

First Thank you very mush "da_st"
the problem was in the keyhash is not was corrent.
so if someone have my problem just used in this code

```
    String TAG = "com.sromku.simple.fb.example";
        PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(TAG,
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature: info.signatures)
        {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            String keyHash = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Log.d(TAG, "keyHash: " + keyHash);
```